# Priority among route patterns

Tags: ruby, url-routing, rack, thin

I have the `thin` server running (without any web application framework). In the routing pattern, the order of matching patterns does not seem to make difference. Whether I do:

```
Rack::Handler::Thin.run(Rack::Builder.new do
  map("/"){...}
  map("/foo/"){...}
end, Port: 3000)
```

or

```
Rack::Handler::Thin.run(Rack::Builder.new do
  map("/foo/"){...}
  map("/"){...}
end, Port: 3000)
```

the request to `localhost:3000/foo/` will be correctly picked up by `map("/foo/"){...}` and not by `map("/"){...}`. How it this priority determined?

For some web application frameworks, for example in [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html), it says `Routes are matched in the order they are defined. The first route that matches the request is invoked`, which is not the case with the setup I have with my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/urlmap.rb

Priority doesn't determined in Rack::URLMap. It matched by full path of the resource, that you provide with

```
map(){ ... }
```

Comment: Your answer does not answer my question, but the page you linked has a description saying `URLMap dispatches in such a way that the longest paths are tried first, since they are most specific`, which answers my question. And lines 38--40 have the relevant code `sort_by do |(host, location, _, _)| [host ? -host.size : INFINITY, -location.size] end`.